# How to have a custom CSS button automatically resize based on an image

Tags: css, button, properties, background

I'm trying to use these images as a basis for the css on a button element [left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKJyd.png) [middle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Puvp.png) [right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvy28.png). The button needs to be able to resize as more text is added by expanding out the middle section (leaving the left and right untouched and not stretched)

I'm currently using

```
background-image: linear-gradient('/img/elements/button/UI-DialogBox-goldbutton-up-middle.png');
```

This works however I can't seem to find a way to add the left and right sides to the button. Any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine all 3 images into 1 button image..

Then, upload into:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Background_and_Borders/Border-image_generator

Answer (score 0):

I tried as mush as I could,

```
<style>
.background-button:before{
    content: " ";
    height: 26px;
    background-image: url('left.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    left: -14px;
    top: -1px;
}

.background-button{
    color: white;
    height: 26px;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin: 0px 14px;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url('mid.png');
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    z-index: 2;
}

.background-button:after{
    content: " ";
    height: 26px;
    background-image: url('right.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 14px;
    right: -14px;
    top: -1px;
}

</style>
<button class = "background-button">Long Long Long Long Long Long Long Long LongButton</button>

<button class = "background-button">Button</button>
```

[image: Screenshot]